# Number Format using Spring

Tags: java, spring, string

I want to have number format using Spring NumberFormat. The number is put in a String. But this gives the same String.

```
@NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER, pattern = "#.###,##")
private static Double amount= "77.7";

public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(amount);
     }
```

Expected output is 77,70

Comment: But what is your expected output ?

Comment: `@NumberFormat` is applicable only for Number type . link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Doesnt work for double